# Why does the multiplication of a matrix to a set of linearly independent vectors still produces a set of linearly independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

More specifically, the question states that the intersection of the null space of a matrix and the set of linearly independent vectors is the zero vector.

How do I use this information to prove the question?

If the intersection of the null space of the matrix and the set of linearly independent vectors is not only the zero vector, is it fair to say that the multiplication of the matrix to the vectors will produce a set of linearly dependent vectors?

Can't make sense of where to start. :/

Comment: It will be best if you tell us exactly what the question says. Presently, since it makes no sense for a matrix to intersect a set of vectors, what you wrote does not make much sense.

Comment: What do you mean with "the intersection of a matrix $B$ and the set of linearly independent vectors"? I think that you're in a hard misunderstood.

Comment: Edited! Sorry about the screw up

Comment: What would "the set of linearly independent vectors" be?

Comment: They're simply stated as "linearly independent vectors in $R^n$".