# Checking if a subset of $R^4$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

$ S = \big\{(2+a+b-2c,2b-c,3c+d,a+3b+d)\ |\ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\big\}$

How do I check if the subset $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: Try by stating the definition of what a (vector) subspace is; add this to your question, at least.  Then see whether the set $S$ matches this definition.

Comment: Try forming zero vector.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, we need to show that

- For every $u,v\in S$, we have $u+v\in S$.
- For every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and every $v\in S$, we have $cv\in S$

In particular we need to show $\mathbf{0}=(0,0,0,0)\in S$.

We claim that $\mathbf{0}\notin S$. We can prove this using the method of contradiction.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction we have $\mathbf{0}\in S$. Therefore

$(1)$   $2+a+b-2c=0$

$(2)$   $2b-c=0$

$(3)$   $3c+d=0$

$(4)$   $a+3b+d=0$

By $(2)$ we can write $c=2b$, and by $(3)$ we can write $d=-3c$.

Thus we can write $(1)$ as $2+a+b-4b=0$, which gives us $2+a-3b=0$. Similarly, using $d=-3c$ we can write $(4)$ as $a+3b-3c=a+3b-6b=0$, which gives us $a=3b$.

Now using $2+a-3b=0$ and $a=3b$, we get $2=0$, which is a contradiction.

This contradiction shows that we cannot have $\mathbf{0}\in S$. Since $\mathbf{0}\notin S$, $S$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I just couldn't quite figure out how to prove that zero vector does not exist in the set of vectors.

Do you mind helping me with this question too? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963197/why-does-the-multiplication-of-a-matrix-to-a-set-of-linearly-independent-vectors?noredirect=1#comment4029730_1963197